# Google Wallet Implementation on React Native for Android SDK

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, google-wallet

Hello I know google launched a react native api for google pay but not anything yet for google wallet. They have 0 samples of it on react yet for google wallet. This is for the android sdk. Does anybody have a npm package for react native of the google wallet api/implementation? Please let me know.

We have it working on native and the google wallet code demo works but it is only for native. We want to make it on react native now.